# Invalid JSON RPC response at Web3.providers.HttpProvider

Tags: web3js

I receive the following error when trying to connect to my private ethereum node with React Native.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "<html>\r\n<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"]
```

Here are my codes:

```
global.Web3 = require("web3");
global.Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx");
global.web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://<username>:<password>@<ethereum node url>'),
);
```

I noted that this happens only when I attempt to connect to a node that requires me to use the pattern 'username:password@nodeurl' because connecting to Infura has no problem at all.

Also, this problem occurs only on React Native. Running this code on Node.JS works fine.

My web3 version is 1.0.0-beta.34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this with some hacks to HttpProvider.

The solution involves making some some changes to \node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js.

I passed the authorization to HttpProvider as a header like this.

```
new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://node-url',0,{Authorization: 'Basic myauthenticationstring'}))
```

And then at \node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js., i changed the following

HttpProvider.prototype._prepareRequest = function(){
    var request = new XHR2();

```
request.open('POST', this.host, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

if(this.headers) {
                            request.setRequestHeader(Object.keys(this.headers)[0], Object.values(this.headers)[0]);
                            /*
    this.headers.forEach(function(header) {
                                            console.log(Object.keys(header.headers));
                                            console.log(Object.values(header.headers));
        //request.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
    });
                            */
}

return request;
```

};